# Spring beginner questions about annotations and thread safety

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am not sure if I am allowed to ask more than one question in a post, but here it is,

For example I have the following,

**Controllers**

```
@Controller
public class FooController{

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody foo(@RequestBody FooRequest request){
    }

}
@Controller
public class BarController{

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/bar", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody bar(@RequestBody FooRequest request){
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
public class FooService{

    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public String doFoo(String str){
        return foo.doFoo(str);
    }
}
```

**class to do the job**

```
public class Foo{

    public String doFoo(String str){
        return (str + " is foo");
    }
}
```

**create beans using dependency injection**

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="fooService" class="com.myapp.service.FooService">
    <property name="foo" ref="foo"></property>
</bean> 
<bean id="foo" class="com.myapp.foo.Foo">
</bean>
```

My questions are:

1. I did not use `@service` annotation at class `FooService`, should I use it, and **why**?
2. Is this configuration thread-safe or not, and **why** (how is it achieved if it is thread-safe)?
3. Where can I find a tutorial about the layers (dao layers, service layer ...) used in Spring design and the purpose of such a design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using it would simply avoid the need for declaring the bean using XML. You chose to use annotations for your other beans. I would thus also use annotations for this one.
2. Yes, it is, because Spring makes sure everything is properly wired up and initialized, with a synchronization barrier, before serving any request
3. This is a very broad question. Layering is useful for separation of concerns, testability, ability to demarcate transactions declaratively, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, "synchronization barrier", on the bean object or on the calling of bean object's methods?

Comment: On the whole application context, AFAIK.

Comment: AFAIK bean initialization is single-threaded per [SPR-8767](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8767)

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't have to use annotations if you declare your beans in xml-config, as you did.
2. It is. Each bean, although a singleton, is stateless. So no concurrent modifications can occur.
3. For example in wikipedia. It's not spring-specific. Look for articles about [three-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

Comment: Thanks, I accept JB'answer because I like his answer more about synchronization barrier. But the three-tier link is very useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1. @Repository, @Service, or @Controller (sub-annotations of @Components) are used to mark specific classes, so they can be considered more-or-less as metadata. However, there are some features of the Spring framework that can take advantage of these. One of them is automatic component scanning (a given java package will be searched for classes with the above annotations and these classes can be used as Spring beans, as if they were declared in XML). To enable this, you should put this into your spring context:

   `<context:component-scan base-package="my.service.package"/>`

   More on this can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning

   Another use-case is for AOP. You can create annotation-aware pointcuts by which you can select say all your repository classes.
2. The Spring beans in context are brought up one by one, so there is no chance of concurrency kicking in. However, there can be circular dependencies between beans and Spring may or may not resolve this properly.
3. For both DAO and service stuff, the current Spring 3 documentation provides many examples and probably the best source for learning: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/index.html If you'd like to have an all-round knowledge I'd recommend trying out JdbcTemplate, Rowmappers and an ORM based configuration with Hibernate.